# How can I use xargs to copy files that have spaces and quotes in their names?

Tags: linux, macos, unix, command-line, xargs

I'm trying to copy a bunch of files below a directory and a number of the files have spaces and single-quotes in their names.  When I try to string together `find` and `grep` with `xargs`, I get the following error:

```
find .|grep "FooBar"|xargs -I{} cp "{}" ~/foo/bar
xargs: unterminated quote
```

Any suggestions for a more robust usage of xargs?

This is on [Mac OS X 10.5.3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Leopard) (Leopard) with BSD `xargs`.

Comment: The GNU xargs error message for this with a filename containing a single quote is rather more helpful: "xargs: unmatched single quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option".

Comment: GNU xargs also has `--delimiter` option (`-d`). Try it with `\n` as the delimiter, This prevents `xargs` from separating lines with spaces into several words/arguments.

Answer (score 215, accepted):

You can combine all of that into a single `find` command:

```
find . -iname "*foobar*" -exec cp -- "{}" ~/foo/bar \;
```

This will handle filenames and directories with spaces in them.  You can use `-name` to get case-sensitive results.

Note: The `--` flag passed to `cp` prevents it from processing files starting with `-` as options.

Comment: -exec will work with any find, I've never understood why people use xargs (and just wait until you hit the xargs directory length limit!!)

Comment: What is an 'xargs directory length limit'? Do you mean maximum command size? If yes, xargs is supposed to split its arguments in appropriate group sizes.

Comment: People use xargs because typically it's faster to call an executable 5 times with 200 arguments each time than to call it 1000 times with one argument every time.

Comment: The answer from Chris Jester-Young ought to be the "good answer" there...  BTW this solution does not work if a filename begins with "-".  At least, it needs "--" after cp.

Comment: Speed example -- over 829 files, the "find -exec" method took 26 seconds while the "find -print0 | xargs --null" method tool 0.7 seconds.  Significant difference.

Comment: Using cp is OK, but not in such way - in this way, cp is run for every file, thus putting non-trivial overhead of fork+execve for every single file. It's better to use -t option of cp. Like: `find .. -exec cp -t ~/foo/bar -- {} +`

Comment: @tzot A late comment but anyway, `xargs` is not required to address the issue you are describing, `find` already supports it with the `-exec` `+` punctuation.

Comment: Hi, if `foobar` is the output of some other command, how can I perform this ? Thank you very much

Comment: @ying17zi Replace `foobar` with either `$(your-command args)` or `\`your-command args\``.

Comment: doesn't answer the question of how to deal with spaces

Comment: @BenGlasser Placing the `{}` within quotation marks protects the spaces within the filename/path. Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: @godbyk no I mean that this answer still has not answered the question about how to handle spaces with xargs, which is the title of the question

Comment: @BenGlasser Ah, gotcha. See Chris' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/143172/4214) for using `xargs` with spaces.

Answer (score 120):

`find . -print0 | grep --null 'FooBar' | xargs -0 ...`

I don't know about whether `grep` supports `--null`, nor whether `xargs` supports `-0`, on Leopard, but on GNU it's all good.

Comment: Leopard does support "-Z" (it is GNU grep) and of course find(1) and xargs(1) do support "-0".

Comment: @Keltia Note that in OS X Mountain Lion (10.8) Apple replaced GNU grep with the BSD grep and the -{z|Z} switch doesn't work.

Comment: On OS X 10.9 `grep -{z|Z}` means "behave as zgrep" (decompress) and not the intended "print a zero byte after each filename". Use `grep --null` to achieve the latter.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young You're very welcome. Although now your comment regarding the "-z" option has lost its context ;)

Comment: What's wrong with `find . -name 'FooBar' -print0 | xargs -0 ...`?

Comment: @QuentinPradet Obviously, for a fixed string like "FooBar", `-name` or `-path` work just fine. The OP has specified the use of `grep`, presumably because they want to filter the list using regular expressions.

Comment: You may get a `Binary file (standard input) matches` from grep when you try this because of `-print0`; use `grep -a` to force it to interpret the pipe.

Comment: Doesn't work with with `duperemove` — passing a 0-ended filename results in `No such file or directory`.

Comment: Ok, I figured, you're using xargs wrong. You should be using `xargs -d '\n'`, otherwise xargs would break files on spaces. Try this: `touch "foo bar"; echo -e "foo bar" | xargs -0 ls`, you'd get an error. But replacing the `-0` with `-d '\n'` works. [See also this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33528111/2388257).

Comment: @Hi-Angel That's _exactly_ why I use `xargs -0` *in conjunction with* `find -print0`. The latter prints filenames with a NUL terminator and the former receives files that way. Why? Filenames in Unix can contain newline characters. But they cannot contain NUL characters.

Comment: Use this if you need other arguments, e.g. target dir for cp: `... | xargs -0 -J % cp -v % /target/dir`

Answer (score 110):

The easiest way to do what the original poster wants is to change the delimiter from any whitespace to just the end-of-line character like this:

```
find whatever ... | xargs -d "\n" cp -t /var/tmp
```

Comment: This anwser is simple, effective, and straight to the point : the default delimiter set for xargs is too broad and needs to be narrowed for what OP wants to do. I know this first-hand because I ran into this exact same issue today doing something similar, except in cygwin. Had I read the help for xargs command, I might have avoided a few headaches, but your solution fixed it for me. Thanks ! (Yeah, OP was on MacOS using BSD xargs, which I don't use, but I have hope that the xargs "-d" parameter exists in all versions).

Comment: Nice answer but not working on Mac. Instead we can pipe the *find* into  `sed -e 's_\(.*\)_"\1"_g'` to force quotes around the file name

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The question was about using `xargs`.

Comment: I get `xargs: illegal option -- d`

Comment: It's worth pointing out that filenames can contain a newline character on many *nix systems. You're unlikely to ever run into this in the wild, but if you're running shell commands on untrusted input this could be a concern.

Comment: (Example: Files `B` and `C` exist in a big directory. A user creates a new file named `B\nC`. Later, that user goes away and someone cleans all that user's files by querying the owners and piping a list of their files through `xargs -d "\n" rm`. Files `B` and `C` are promptly deleted.)

Comment: @nehem `-d` is a GNU option, so if you're on mac you'll need to install GNU tools

Answer (score 78):

This is more efficient as it does not run "cp" multiple times:

```
find -name '*FooBar*' -print0 | xargs -0 cp -t ~/foo/bar
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. It tried to cp ~/foo/bar into whatever you find, but not the opposite

Comment: The -t flag to cp is a GNU extension, AFAIK, and isn't available on OS X. But if it were, it would work as shown in this answer.

Comment: I'm using Linux. Thanks for the '-t' switch. That's what I was missing :-)

Comment: It works for me! +1 vote

Answer (score 64):

I ran into the same problem. Here's how I solved it:

```
find . -name '*FoooBar*' | sed 's/.*/"&"/' | xargs cp ~/foo/bar
```

I used `sed` to substitute each line of input with the same line, but surrounded by double quotes. From the `sed` man page, "*...An ampersand (``&'') appearing in the replacement is replaced by the string matching the RE...*" -- in this case, `.*`, the entire line.

This solves the `xargs: unterminated quote` error.

Comment: I'm on windows and using gnuwin32, so I had to use `sed s/.*/\"&\"/` to get it to work.

Comment: Yes but presumably this would not handle filenames with `"` in - unless sed also quotes quotes?

Comment: Using `sed` is genius and for now the correct solution without rewriting the problem!

Answer (score 58):

This method works on [Mac OS X v10.7.5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Lion) (Lion):

```
find . | grep FooBar | xargs -I{} cp {} ~/foo/bar
```

I also tested the exact syntax you posted. That also worked fine on 10.7.5.

Comment: This works, but `-I` implies `-L 1` (so says the manual), which means the cp command is being run once per file = v slow.

Comment: xargs -J % cp % <destination dir> Is possibly more efficient on OSX.

Comment: Sorry, but this is WRONG. First it produces exactly the error the TO wanted to avoid. You must use `find ... -print0` and `xargs -0` to work arround xargs's "by default quotes are special". Second, generally use `'{}'` not `{}` in commands passed to xargs, to protect against spaces and special characters.

Comment: Sorry Andreas Spindler, I am not that familiar with xargs and found this line after some experimentation. It seems to work for most people who have commented on it and upvoted it. Would you mind going into a bit more detail about what kind of error it produces?

Also, would you mind posting the exact input you think would be more correct? Thank you.

Comment: This is the xargs part that worked on *MacOS* 10.15 for me: `xargs -0 -J % cp -v % /foo/bar`

Answer (score 13):

Just don't use `xargs`. It is a neat program but it doesn't go well with `find` when faced with non trivial cases.

Here is a portable (POSIX) solution, i.e. one that doesn't require `find`, `xargs` or `cp` GNU specific extensions:

```
find . -name "*FooBar*" -exec sh -c 'cp -- "$@" ~/foo/bar' sh {} +
```

Note the ending `+` instead of the more usual `;`.

This solution:

- correctly handles files and directories with embedded spaces, newlines or whatever exotic characters.
- works on any Unix and Linux system, even those not providing the GNU toolkit.
- doesn't use `xargs` which is a nice and useful program, but requires too much tweaking and non standard features to properly handle `find` output.
- is also **more efficient** (read **faster**) than the accepted and most if not all of the other answers.

Note also that despite what is stated in some other replies or comments quoting `{}` is useless (unless you are using the exotic `fish`shell).

Comment: Why is it faster? [User tzot wrote: *"People use xargs because typically it's faster to call an executable 5 times with 200 arguments each time than to call it 1000 times with one argument every time."*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143171/how-can-i-use-xargs-to-copy-files-that-have-spaces-and-quotes-in-their-names#comment75541_143222)

Comment: @PeterMortensen You probably overlook the ending plus. `find` can do what `xargs` does without any overhead.

Answer (score 11):

For those who relies on commands, other than find, eg `ls`:

```
find . | grep "FooBar" | tr \\n \\0 | xargs -0 -I{} cp "{}" ~/foo/bar
```

Comment: Works but slow because `-I` implies `-L 1`

Comment: The only answer that worked for me in 2023. Replace newlines with \0. Simple, smart, works

Answer (score 8):

Look into using the --null commandline option for xargs with the -print0 option in find.

Answer (score 6):

```
find | perl -lne 'print quotemeta' | xargs ls -d
```

I believe that this will work reliably for any character except line-feed (and I suspect that if you've got line-feeds in your filenames, then you've got worse problems than this).  It doesn't require GNU findutils, just Perl, so it should work pretty-much anywhere.

Comment: Is it possible to have a line-feed in a filename? Never heard of it.

Comment: Indeed it is.  Try, e.g., `mkdir test && cd test && perl -e 'open $fh, ">", "this-file-contains-a-\n-here"' && ls | od -tx1`

Comment: `|perl -lne 'print quotemeta'` is exactly what I have been looking for. Other posts here didn't help me because rather than `find` I needed to use `grep -rl` to vastly reduce the number of PHP files to only the malware-infected ones.

Comment: perl and quotemeta are far more general than print0/-0 - thanks for the general solution to pipelining files with spaces

Answer (score 5):

I have found that the following syntax works well for me.

```
find /usr/pcapps/ -mount -type f -size +1000000c | perl -lpe ' s{ }{\\ }g ' | xargs ls -l | sort +4nr | head -200
```

In this example, I am looking for the largest 200 files over 1,000,000 bytes in the filesystem mounted at "/usr/pcapps".

The Perl line-liner between "find" and "xargs" escapes/quotes each blank so "xargs" passes any filename with embedded blanks to "ls" as a single argument.

Answer (score 4):

Frame challenge — you're asking how to use xargs.  The answer is: you don't use xargs, because you don't need it.

The [comment by `user80168`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143171/how-can-i-use-xargs-to-copy-files-that-have-spaces-and-quotes-in-their-names#comment20387811_143222) describes a way to do this directly with cp, without calling cp for every file:

```
find . -name '*FooBar*' -exec cp -t /tmp -- {} +
```

This works because:

- the `cp -t` flag allows to give the target directory near the beginning of `cp`, rather than near the end.  From `man cp`:

> ```
>    -t, --target-directory=DIRECTORY
>          copy all SOURCE arguments into DIRECTORY
> ```

- The `--` flag tells `cp` to interpret everything after as a filename, not a flag, so files starting with `-` or `--` do not confuse `cp`; you still need this because the `-`/`--` characters are interpreted by `cp`, whereas any other special characters are interpreted by the shell.
- The `find -exec command {} +` variant essentially does the same as xargs.  From `man find`:

> ```
>    -exec command {} +                                                     
>          This  variant  of the -exec action runs the specified command on
>          the selected files, but the command line is built  by  appending
>          each  selected file name at the end; the total number of invoca‐
>          matched  files.   The command line is built in much the same way
>          that xargs builds its command lines.  Only one instance of  `{}'
>          is  allowed  within the command, and (when find is being invoked
>          from a shell) it should be quoted (for example, '{}') to protect
>          it  from  interpretation  by shells.  The command is executed in
>          the starting directory.  If any invocation  returns  a  non-zero
>          value  as exit status, then find returns a non-zero exit status.
>          If find encounters an error, this can sometimes cause an immedi‐
>          ate  exit, so some pending commands may not be run at all.  This
>          variant of -exec always returns true.
> ```

By using this in find directly, this avoids the need of a pipe or a shell invocation, such that you don't need to worry about any nasty characters in filenames.

Comment: Amazing find, I had no idea!!!
"     -exec utility [argument ...] {} +
             Same as -exec, except that ``{}'' is replaced with as many pathnames as possible for each invocation of utility.  This behaviour is similar to that of xargs(1)." in the BSD implementation.

Answer (score 3):

With Bash (not POSIX) you can use process substitution to get the current line inside a variable. This enables you to use quotes to escape special characters:

```
while read line ; do cp "$line" ~/bar ; done < <(find . | grep foo)
```

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that most of the options discussed in other answers are not standard on platforms that do not use the GNU utilities (Solaris, AIX, HP-UX, for instance).  See the [POSIX](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/toc.htm) specification for 'standard' xargs behaviour.

I also find the behaviour of xargs whereby it runs the command at least once, even with no input, to be a nuisance.

I wrote my own private version of xargs (xargl) to deal with the problems of spaces in names (only newlines separate  - though the 'find ... -print0' and 'xargs -0' combination is pretty neat given that file names cannot contain ASCII NUL '\0' characters.  My xargl isn't as complete as it would need to be to be worth publishing - especially since GNU has facilities that are at least as good.

Comment: GitHub or it didn't happen

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg: I guess it didn't happen then.

Comment: POSIX `find` doesn't need `xargs` in the first place (and that was already true 11 years ago).

Answer (score 2):

For me, I was trying to do something a little different. I wanted to copy my .txt files into my tmp folder. The .txt filenames contain spaces and apostrophe characters. This worked on my Mac.

```
$ find . -type f -name '*.txt' | sed 's/'"'"'/\'"'"'/g' | sed 's/.*/"&"/'  | xargs -I{} cp -v {} ./tmp/
```

Answer (score 1):

[bill_starr's Perl version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143171/how-can-i-use-xargs-to-copy-files-that-have-spaces-and-quotes-in-their-names#474907) won't work well for embedded newlines (only copes with spaces). For those on e.g. Solaris where you don't have the GNU tools, a more complete version might be (using sed)...

```
find -type f | sed 's/./\\&/g' | xargs grep string_to_find
```

adjust the find and grep arguments or other commands as you require, but the sed will fix your embedded newlines/spaces/tabs.

Answer (score 1):

I used [Bill Star's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143171/how-can-i-use-xargs-to-copy-files-that-have-spaces-and-quotes-in-their-names#474907) slightly modified on Solaris:

```
find . -mtime +2 | perl -pe 's{^}{\"};s{$}{\"}' > ~/output.file
```

This will put quotes around each line. I didn't use the '-l' option although it probably would help.

The file list I was going though might have '-', but not newlines. I haven't used the output file with any other commands as I want to review what was found before I just start massively deleting them via xargs.

Answer (score 1):

If find and xarg versions on your system doesn't support `-print0` and `-0` switches (for example AIX find and xargs) you can use this terribly looking code:

```
 find . -name "*foo*" | sed -e "s/'/\\\'/g" -e 's/"/\\"/g' -e 's/ /\\ /g' | xargs cp /your/dest
```

Here sed will take care of escaping the spaces and quotes for xargs.

Tested on AIX 5.3

Answer (score 1):

I played with this a little, started contemplating modifying xargs, and realised that for the kind of use case we're talking about here, a simple reimplementation in Python is a better idea.

For one thing, having ~80 lines of code for the whole thing means it is easy to figure out what is going on, and if different behaviour is required, you can just hack it into a new script in less time than it takes to get a reply on somewhere like Stack Overflow.

See https://github.com/johnallsup/jda-misc-scripts/blob/master/yargs and https://github.com/johnallsup/jda-misc-scripts/blob/master/zargs.py.

With yargs as written (and Python 3 installed) you can type:

```
find .|grep "FooBar"|yargs -l 203 cp --after ~/foo/bar
```

to do the copying 203 files at a time. (Here 203 is just a placeholder, of course, and using a strange number like 203 makes it clear that this number has no other significance.)

If you really want something faster and without the need for Python, take zargs and yargs as prototypes and rewrite in C++ or C.

Answer (score 1):

I created a small portable wrapper script called "xargsL" around "xargs" which addresses most of the problems.

Contrary to xargs, xargsL accepts one pathname per line. The pathnames may contain any character except (obviously) newline or NUL bytes.

No quoting is allowed or supported in the file list - your file names may contain all sorts of whitespace, backslashes, backticks, shell wildcard characters and the like - xargsL will process them as literal characters, no harm done.

As an added bonus feature, xargsL will *not* run the command once if there is no input!

Note the difference:

```
$ true | xargs echo no data
no data

$ true | xargsL echo no data # No output
```

Any arguments given to xargsL will be passed through to xargs.

Here is the "xargsL" POSIX shell script:

> ```
> #! /bin/sh
> # Line-based version of "xargs" (one pathname per line which may contain any
> # amount of whitespace except for newlines) with the added bonus feature that
> # it will not execute the command if the input file is empty.
> #
> # Version 2018.76.3
> #
> # Copyright (c) 2018 Guenther Brunthaler. All rights reserved.
> #
> # This script is free software.
> # Distribution is permitted under the terms of the GPLv3.
>
> set -e
> trap 'test $? = 0 || echo "$0 failed!" >& 2' 0
>
> if IFS= read -r first
> then
>         {
>                 printf '%s\n' "$first"
>                 cat
>         } | sed 's/./\\&/g' | xargs ${1+"$@"}
> fi
> ```

Put the script into some directory in your $PATH and don't forget to

`$ chmod +x xargsL`

the script there to make it executable.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to grep Foobar directory like:

```
find . -name "file.ext"| grep "FooBar" | xargs -i cp -p "{}" .
```

Comment: Per the man page, `-i` is deprecated, and `-I` should be used instead.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Bash, you can convert *stdout* to an array of lines by `mapfile`:

```
find . | grep "FooBar" | (mapfile -t; cp "${MAPFILE[@]}" ~/foobar)
```

The benefits are:

- It's built-in, so it's faster.
- Execute the command with all file names in one time, so it's faster.
- You can append other arguments to the file names. For `cp`, you can also:

  ```
  find . -name '*FooBar*' -exec cp -t ~/foobar -- {} +
  ```

  however, some commands don't have such feature.

The disadvantages:

- Maybe not scale well if there are too many file names. (The limit? I don't know, but I had tested with 10 MB list file which includes 10000+ file names with no problem, under Debian)

Well... who knows if Bash is available on OS X?