# how to output file names surrounded with quotes in SINGLE line?

Tags: bash, unix, find, xargs

I would like to output the list of items in a folder in the folowing way:

```
"filename1"  "filename2" "file name with spaces" "foldername" "folder name with spaces"
```

In other words, item names must be in a single line, surrounded with quotes (single or double) and divided by spaces.

I know that

```
find . | xargs echo
```

prints output in a single line, but I do not know how to add quotes around each item name.

This code is part of a bsh script.
The solution can therefore be a set of commands and use temporary files for storing intermediate output.

Thank you very much for any suggestion.

Cheers, Ana

Comment: If the goal is to pass names with spaces to xargs, literal quotes are the wrong way to do it.

Comment: Indeed, I just spent too long researching this and what I wanted, to pass found output to `rm` removing files older than a year, was: `find ./backups -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +365 -print0 | xargs -0 -r rm -f`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

this should work

```
find $PWD | sed 's/^/"/g' | sed 's/$/"/g' | tr '\n' ' '
```

EDIT:

This should be more efficient than the previous one.

```
find $PWD | sed -e 's/^/"/g' -e 's/$/"/g' | tr '\n' ' '
```

@Timofey's solution would work with a tr in the end, and should be the most efficient.

```
find $PWD -exec echo -n '"{}" ' \; | tr '\n' ' '
```

Comment: This works great! Thank you very much. My final command is now: "find . ! -type l \( -name . -o -prune \) | sort -n | sed 's/^/"/g' | sed 's/$/"/g' | tr '\n' ' ' | xargs myCommand". This single line was needed as input parameter for myCommand.

Comment: Please, please no. First, `find $PWD` will behave badly if your `$PWD` contains spaces or literal glob characters that expand to anything. Second, substituting double quotes around a name to try to escape it is a weak and easily circumvented mechanism -- valid filenames can themselves contain `"` or `'` characters, thus throwing off parsing for the entire rest of the stream.

Comment: @Ana, if on a system with GNU tools (`find -print0` and `sort -z`), it's far better to use `find ... -print0 | sort -n -z | xargs -0 myCommand`

Comment: @Ana, ...even if you don't want to use NUL delimiters, you can still tell `xargs` to use only newline delimiters and be safe against filenames with spaces (albeit not filenames with newlines, but the answer you've already accepted is also already unsafe against filenames containing newline literals): `find ... | sort -n | xargs -d $'\n' myCommand`

Comment: You should really use "ls" to list directory contents. It DO have the needed options.

Comment: But how to give this output with quoted to XARGS input for another command execution ?

Answer (score 64):

You could also simply use find "-printf", as in :

```
find . -printf "\"%p\" " | xargs your_command
```

where:

```
%p = file-path
```

This will surround every found file-path with quotes and separate each item with a space.
This avoids the use of multiple commands.

Comment: This should be marked the correct answer. The regex manipulation is too low-level.

Comment: I had to add a new line using cygwin on Windows for the output to be the same: `-printf "\"%p\" \n"`

Comment: -printf Not available on OSX.

Comment: @Nimrod With Homebrew: `brew install findutils --with-default-names`

Comment: ...which fails spectacularly if the filename contains quotes.

Comment: Why have you included `your_command`? I thought the question had the single use case of listing the files in a directory with quotes around their names.

Answer (score 20):

Try this.

```
find . -exec echo -n '"{}" ' \;
```

Comment: remove -n to get the result with newlines included.

Comment: Doesn't work on Solaris 11, just prints `-n "{}"` lots of times!

Comment: If you want to remove the leading `./`, try this: `find * -exec echo -n '"{}" ' \;`

Comment: While it works great in Alpine, it doesn't work in Debian/Ubuntu unfortunately...

Answer (score 20):

You can use the GNU `ls` option `--quoting-style` to easily get what you are after.  From the manual page:

> `--quoting-style=WORD`
>
> > use quoting style  `WORD`  for  entry  names: `literal`,  `locale`,  `shell`, `shell-always`, `shell-escape`, `shell-escape-always`, `c`, `escape`

For example, using the command `ls --quoting-style=shell-escape-always`, your output becomes:

```
'filename1' 'filename2' 'file name with spaces' 'foldername' 'folder name with spaces'
```

Using `--quoting-style=c`, you can reproduce your desired example exactly.  However, if the output is going to be used by a shell script, you should use one of the forms that correctly escapes special characters, such as `shell-escape-always`.

Comment: related: 'ls -Q' ;# adds double quotes

Comment: I suggest: `ls -1 --quoting-style=c` -->  `"file one"  "file two" etc.`.  Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

After 10 years, no one suggested the Bash "|while read" method?

```
find * -type d -depth 0|while read f; do echo \"$f\"; done
```

It's a simple Bash shell pipeline instead of launching another program like sed or xarg. If you really want to do something with each file/folder:

```
find * -type d -depth 0|while read f; do du -sh "$f"; done
```

By the way, `find *` uses another Bash feature that excludes .xyz files/folders and will not output the `./` prefix `find .` does.

Answer (score 5):

```
for f in *; do printf "'%s' " "$f"; done; echo
```

Or, thanks to [Gordon Davisson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89817/gordon-davisson):

```
printf "'%s' " *; echo
```

The trailing `echo` is simply to add a newline to the output.

Comment: This can be simplified even further: `printf "'%s' " *`.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**
The following answer generate a *new-line separated LIST* instead of a single line.

1. I'm second guessing that the OP uses the result for invoking other command
2. converting the output LIST to single line is easy (`| tr '\n' ' '`)

---

A less mentioned method is to use `-d` (`--delimiter`) option of `xargs`:

```
find . | xargs -I@ -d"\n" echo \"@\"
```

> `-I@` captures each `find` result as `@` and then we echo-ed it with quotes

With this you can invoke any commands just as you added quotes to the arguments.

```
$ find . | xargs -d"\n" testcli.js
[ "filename1",
  "filename2",
  "file name with spaces",
  "foldername",
  "folder name with spaces" ]
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/33528111/665507

Answer (score 1):

try

```
ls | sed -e 's/^/"/g' -e 's/$/"/g' | tr '\n' ' '
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    find . | sed "s|.*|\"&\"|"
```

**Brief description:**
We take result of .* pattern and put it into quotes.
Good source is [sed](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html).
**Detail description:**
Pattern: **s/one/ONE/**

- **s** Substitute command.
- **/** Delimiter.
  In my expression **"|"** is used instead of **"/"** to prevent "mountains" like in pattern s/.*/\"&\"/.
- **one** Regular expression pattern search pattern.
- **ONE** Replacement string.
- **.*** Means any symbol that repeats unlimited number of times.
- **\"** Means **"** itself.
- **&** Special character that corresponds to the pattern found.

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
find . -print0 | xargs -0 echo
```

the `-print0` argument makes the output null-terminated instead of a new-line, and the `-0` on xargs says to use null as the delimiter. As such, spaces are preserved as you would expect without the need to quote things.

Answer (score -1):

To avoid hacks trying to manually add quotes, you can take advantage of `printf`s `%q` formatting option:

```
❯ ll .zshrc.d
total 112K
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  378 Jul  1 04:39  options.zsh*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   57 Jul  1 04:39  history.zsh*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  301 Jul  1 05:01  zinit.zsh*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  79K Jul  1 05:19  p10k.zsh*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  345 Jul  1 05:24  zplugins.zsh*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  490 Jul  4 23:40  aliases.zsh*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 9.0K Jul 27 08:14  lscolors.zsh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Aug 30 05:56 'foo bar'
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Aug 30 05:58 '"foo"'

❯ find .zshrc.d -exec printf '%q ' {} +
.zshrc.d .zshrc.d/history.zsh .zshrc.d/aliases.zsh .zshrc.d/zplugins.zsh .zshrc.d/p10k.zsh .zshrc.d/zinit.zsh .zshrc.d/options.zsh '.zshrc.d/"foo"' '.zshrc.d/foo bar' .zshrc.d/lscolors.zsh #
```

vs:

```
find .zshrc.d -printf "\"%p\" "
".zshrc.d" ".zshrc.d/history.zsh" ".zshrc.d/aliases.zsh" ".zshrc.d/zplugins.zsh" ".zshrc.d/p10k.zsh" ".zshrc.d/zinit.zsh" ".zshrc.d/options.zsh" ".zshrc.d/"foo"" ".zshrc.d/foo bar" ".zshrc.d/lscolors.zsh" #
```

Notice the file `.zshrc.d/"foo"` is incorrectly escaped.

```
❯ echo ".zshrc.d/"foo""
.zshrc.d/foo

❯ echo '.zshrc.d/"foo"'
.zshrc.d/"foo"
```