# silver_searcher (ag) with multiple search expressions?

Tags: full-text-search, ag

Does [silver_searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) support specifying multiple search expressions something like `-e` in `grep`?

I could not find any option in the document/help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the documentation, it doesn't support multiple search patterns. That said, it does support using parallel, so you can fire off multiple instances of ag for a multi-search:

```
echo "foo\nbar\nbaz" | parallel 'ag --parallel --color "{}" *'
```

The output using the --parallel switch will be filename, linenumber and match. If that's too fancy, you can always use the OR operator in your pattern search:

```
ag --color "foo|bar|baz" *
```

Answer (score 17):

You might want to search with both Boolean operators:

- **[AND](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher/issues/551#issuecomment-310805058)**: `ag -l pattern1 | xargs ag -l pattern2 | xargs ag 'pattern1|pattern2'`

  - [Add `-d '\n'`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32589977/4970442) to xargs to handle spaces on filenames.
- **OR**: `ag 'pattern1|pattern2'`
- **NOT**: `ag -v 'pattern'`

[From manual](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher/blob/master/doc/ag.1.md):

> `-l` `--files-with-matches`:
> Only print the names of files containing matches, not the matching lines. An empty query will print all files that would be searched.

> `-v` `--invert-match`: Match every line not containing the specified pattern.

Comment: `Add -d '\n' to xargs to handle spaces on filenames.` That's a really useful tip. I usually try to mess with `-0`. What do you do if the path has parentheses or ~ in it?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can search for multiple patterns by separating each pattern with a vertical line character (`|`):

```
ag 'pattern1|pattern2'
```