# merge 1000s of csv with same name in different subdirectories

Tags: python-2.7

I have 1000 of subdirectories (error1 - error1000) with three different csv files (rand.csv, run_error.csv, swe_error.csv). Each vsc has index row. I need to merge the csv files that have the same filename, so I end up with e.g. rand_merge.csv with index row and 1000 rows of data.

I followed [Merge multiple csv files with same name in 10 different subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43948049/merge-multiple-csv-files-with-same-name-in-10-different-subdirectory), which gets me

> KeyError: 'filename'

I can't figure out how to fix it, so any help is appreciated.
Thx

Update: Here's the exact code, which came from linked post above:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

CONCAT_DIR = "./error/files_concat/"

# Use glob module to return all csv files under root directory. Create DF from this.
files = pd.DataFrame([file for file in glob.glob("error/*/*")], columns=["fullpath"])


# Split the full path into directory and filename
files_split = files['fullpath'].str.rsplit("\\", 1, expand=True).rename(columns={0: 'path', 1:'filename'})


# Join these into one DataFrame
files = files.join(files_split)


# Iterate over unique filenames; read CSVs, concat DFs, save file
for f in files['filename'].unique():
    paths = files[files['filename'] == f]['fullpath'] # Get list of fullpaths from unique filenames
    dfs = [pd.read_csv(path, header=None) for path in paths] # Get list of dataframes from CSV file paths
    concat_df = pd.concat(dfs) # Concat dataframes into one
    concat_df.to_csv(CONCAT_DIR + f) # Save dataframe
```

Comment: Please include the code that generates the error you are seeing.

Comment: @Engineero I added the code to OP

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake. I needed a "/" after rsplit, not "\"

```
files_split = files['fullpath'].str.rsplit("/", 1, expand=True).rename(columns={0: 'path', 1:'filename'})
```