# Merge 10000 csv in different folders while keeping sorted

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, csv, glob

I have 10,000 folders (test1, test2,..., test10000), each folder contains the same five .csv files (real.csv, model.csv, run.csv, swe.csv, error.csv), but the values in each are different.

I need to combine each csv with the same filename into 1 csv, i.e. produce a concatenated .csv (e.g. real.csv) with all the data from the 10,000 .csv (real.csv) files. AND I need the concatenated .csv to be sorted, i.e. I need row 1 to be from test1, row 2 to be from test2,..., row 10,000 from test10000.

I have used the code from here as blueprint and edited it to sort. [Merge multiple csv files with same name in 10 different subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43948049/merge-multiple-csv-files-with-same-name-in-10-different-subdirectory)

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

concat_dir = '/home/zachary/workspace/lineartransfer/error/files_concat/'

files = pd.DataFrame([file for file in glob.glob("/home/zachary/workspace/lineartransfer/error/*/*")], columns=["fullpath"])

# Split the full path into directory and filename
files_split = files['fullpath'].str.rsplit("/", 1, expand=True).rename(columns={0: 'path', 1: 'filename'})

# Join these into one DataFrame
files = files.join(files_split)

# Iterate over unique filenames; read CSVs, concat DFs, save file
for f in files['filename'].unique():
    paths = files[files['filename'] == f]['fullpath'] # Get list of fullpaths from unique filenames
    dfs = [pd.read_csv(path, header=None) for path in sorted(paths)] # Get list of dataframes from CSV file paths
    concat_df = pd.concat(dfs) # Concat dataframes into one
    concat_df.to_csv(concat_dir + f) # Save dataframe
```

The above code works, but I get sorting of:
1
10
100
1000
10000
1001
1002
...
102
1020
1021
...

I need sorting:
1
2
3
...
10000

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an numeric-alpha sort which takes into account numbers and their values, even when they are embedded in a string.

```
from functools import cmp_to_key

def nasort(x, y):
    fx = re.sub(r'(\d+)', r'{:099d}', x)
    fy = re.sub(r'(\d+)', r'{:099d}', y)
    ax = map(int, re.sub(r'([^\d]+)', r' ', x).strip().split(' '))
    ay = map(int, re.sub(r'([^\d]+)', r' ', y).strip().split(' '))
    _x = fx.format(*ax)
    _y = fy.format(*ay)
    if   str(_x) > str(_y): return 1
    elif str(_x) < str(_y): return -1
    else: return 0

print (sorted(['file5', 'file2', 'file4', 'file1', 'file10']))
print (sorted(['file5', 'file2', 'file4', 'file1', 'file10'], key=cmp_to_key(nasort)))
```

The first line (output array) is the standard sort.
The second line (output array) is the new sort where file10 comes after file5.

`['file1', 'file10', 'file2', 'file4', 'file5']
['file1', 'file2', 'file4', 'file5', 'file10']`

Comment: Please note that for python2 you can use sorted(..., cmp=nasort)