# syntax error near unexpected token `(' using convert

Tags: terminal, find

I'm trying to run the `convert` command on some images to resize them.

```
find build_reports/functional_tests/results -name '*.png' | xargs -I {} sh -c 'convert -resize 20% {} {}'
```

The problem that I have is that the files have ( and ) in their names (e.g. build_reports/functional_tests/results/Attachments/Screenshot of main screen (ID 1)_1_0FEF8183-AF87-4517-928D-8C4A2ED984D0.png) and I cannot rename these files because their linked somewhere else.

When I run the command I get the following warnings and the images are not resized

```
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `convert -resize 20% build_reports/functional_tests/results/Attachments/Screenshot of main screen (ID 1)_1_D94BAEBC-F463-4EEE-8FAE-C49AFF4A8FFE.png {}'
```

Is there anyway to get rid of these warning and make this work by somehow escaping the result of the find command?

Comment: Use -print0 in find and -0 in xargs, and put the file names between quotes: find /path -print0 -name *.png | xargs -I {} -0 convert... '{}' '{}'

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16758525/how-can-i-make-xargs-handle-filenames-that-contain-spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try to this:

```
find . -iname "*.png" -exec convert -resize 20% '{}' '{}' \;
```

Notice the single quotes`'{}'`