# Why cat does not work with parameter -0 in xargs?

Tags: shell, sh, freebsd, xargs

I am trying to implement this solution:

[Make xargs handle filenames that contain spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16758525/make-xargs-handle-filenames-that-contain-spaces)

to `cat` several files that are to be selected using `find`.

Therefore, I have tried to implement the BSD solution provided in that post, but if I do:

```
$ find "/tmp/database"  -name "FOO 03-11*" 
/tmp/database/01/FOO 03-11.txt
/tmp/database/03/FOO 03-11.txt
/tmp/database/02/FOO 03-11.txt
/tmp/database/05/FOO 03-11.txt
/tmp/database/04/FOO 03-11.txt

$ find "/tmp/database"  -name "FOO 03-11*" | sort 
/tmp/database/01/FOO 03-11.txt
/tmp/database/02/FOO 03-11.txt
/tmp/database/03/FOO 03-11.txt
/tmp/database/04/FOO 03-11.txt
/tmp/database/05/FOO 03-11.txt

$ find "/tmp/database"  -name "FOO 03-11*" | sort | xargs -0
/tmp/database/01/FOO 03-11.txt
/tmp/database/02/FOO 03-11.txt
/tmp/database/03/FOO 03-11.txt
/tmp/database/04/FOO 03-11.txt
/tmp/database/05/FOO 03-11.txt

$ find "/tmp/database"  -name "FOO 03-11*" | sort | xargs -0 cat
cat: /tmp/database/01/FOO 03-11.txt
/tmp/database/02/FOO 03-11.txt
/tmp/database/03/FOO 03-11.txt
/tmp/database/04/FOO 03-11.txt
/tmp/database/05/FOO 03-11.txt
: No such file or directory
$
```

I still can not get the `cat` command working. What is missing from the accepted answer of the provided post to get `cat` working with `xargs -0`?

I am using FreeBSD 12 and its shell `/bin/sh` which as far as I know is POSIX.

I would -clearly wrongly- expect this `find/sort/xargs/cat` sequence to output the contents of the file as in:

```
$ cat "/tmp/database/01/FOO 03-11.txt"
CONTENT OF FILE /tmp/database/01/FOO 03-11.txt
$ cat "/tmp/database/02/FOO 03-11.txt"
CONTENT OF FILE /tmp/database/02/FOO 03-11.txt
$ cat "/tmp/database/03/FOO 03-11.txt"
CONTENT OF FILE /tmp/database/03/FOO 03-11.txt
$ cat "/tmp/database/04/FOO 03-11.txt"
CONTENT OF FILE /tmp/database/04/FOO 03-11.txt
$ cat "/tmp/database/05/FOO 03-11.txt"
CONTENT OF FILE /tmp/database/05/FOO 03-11.txt
```

So the expected output would be:

```
$ find "/tmp/database"  -name "FOO 03-11*" | sort | xargs -0 cat
CONTENT OF FILE /tmp/database/01/FOO 03-11.txt
CONTENT OF FILE /tmp/database/02/FOO 03-11.txt
CONTENT OF FILE /tmp/database/03/FOO 03-11.txt
CONTENT OF FILE /tmp/database/04/FOO 03-11.txt
CONTENT OF FILE /tmp/database/05/FOO 03-11.txt
```

Comment: It works - there is no such directory. `xargs` properly passed the input to `cat` - it works, correctly, and then `cat` tells you that there is no such directory - also, most probably, correctly. Did you expect something else? Why? What do you think `-0` means?

Comment: The files are under `/tmp/database/0x` and I want to cat them. I have edited the question so the expected output is more clear.

Comment: If you can exclude the possibility that you may have one day so many files that you would get an _arglist too long_ error if you feed them all together into a single `cat`, you could also do a `cat $(find ...| sort)`.

Comment: I tried and that solution does not work with files with spaces in the name, at least not in `/bin/sh` in FreeBSD `$ cat $(find "/tmp/database"  -name "FOO 03-11*" | sort) 
cat: /tmp/database/01/FOO: No such file or directory ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FreeBSD `xargs` does not support `-d` as suggested in a deleted answer, but the answer was useful as it clarified `-0` usage and gives the hint to handle the new line characters as delimiters, so an inclusion of `tr` to turn `\n` into `\0` can do the trick for FreeBSD:

```
$ find "/tmp/database"  -name "FOO 03-11*" | sort | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 cat
CONTENT OF FILE /tmp/database/01/FOO 03-11.txt
CONTENT OF FILE /tmp/database/02/FOO 03-11.txt
CONTENT OF FILE /tmp/database/03/FOO 03-11.txt
CONTENT OF FILE /tmp/database/04/FOO 03-11.txt
CONTENT OF FILE /tmp/database/05/FOO 03-11.txt
```

As a side note, in GNU Linux it could be used `-d '\n'`:

```
find "/tmp/database"  -name "FOO 03-11*" | sort | xargs -d '\n' cat
```

Comment: According to online manuals `find '/tmp/database' -name 'FOO 03-11*' -print0 | sort -z | xargs -0 cat` should work on FreeBSD. The one in your answer breaks if a file contains `'`, `"`, ```\```, or a line break in its name, this one doesn't.

Comment: Thanks I confirm that it actually works in FreeBSD, I was not aware on `-z` and `-print0` arguments. In this particular case I do not intend to deal with files containing `'`,`"` or \ (which are arguably bad character choices for a filename) but it is an useful clarification.