# How to move or copy files listed by 'find' command in unix?

Tags: unix, find, cp, mv

I have a list of certain files that I see using the command below, but how can I copy those files listed into another folder, say ~/test?

```
find . -mtime 1 -exec du -hc {} +
```

Comment: `find . -mtime 1 -exec cp {} ~/test/ \;`

Comment: Also, consider piping to `xargs`.  That way, you can copy the files in batches.

Comment: In regards to @EricJablow - you are correct. But also if you run `-exec` with a `+;` at the end of the statement it will copy in a single batch and if you use `\;` it will run a `cp` command for each file found. Cheers!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find and copy files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241625/find-and-copy-files)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Adding to Eric Jablow's answer, here is a possible solution (it worked for me - linux mint 14 /nadia)

```
find /path/to/search/ -type f -name "glob-to-find-files" | xargs cp -t /target/path/
```

You can refer to "[How can I use xargs to copy files that have spaces and quotes in their names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143171/how-can-i-use-xargs-to-copy-files-that-have-spaces-and-quotes-in-their-names/149026#149026)" as well.

Comment: `-name` takes a glob match, not a regular expression. An important distinction...

Comment: It looks like **xargs** is more efficient than **exec** in situations where copying significant number of files.

Comment: Eduardo, can you share the results, if you have performed any benchmarking tests?

Comment: What does `-t` do with `cp`? Can't find that option on Mac terminal in `man cp`.

Comment: @kontur -- You may want to go through this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/62122320/1031939

Answer (score 31):

Actually, you can process the `find` command output in a copy command in two ways:

1. If the `find` command's output doesn't contain any space, i.e if the filename doesn't contain a space in it, then you can use:

   ```
   Syntax:
       find <Path> <Conditions> | xargs cp -t <copy file path>
   Example:
       find -mtime -1 -type f | xargs cp -t inner/
   ```
2. But our production data files might contain spaces, so most of time this command is effective:

   ```
   Syntax:
      find <path> <condition> -exec cp '{}' <copy path> \;

   Example 
      find -mtime -1 -type f -exec cp '{}' inner/ \;
   ```

In the second example, the last part, the semi-colon is also considered as part of the `find` command, and should be escaped before pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Otherwise you will get an error something like:

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

Comment: if no file is found, then cp will throw error: `cp: missing file operand`. how to ignore this?

Answer (score 20):

```
find /PATH/TO/YOUR/FILES -name NAME.EXT -exec cp -rfp {} /DST_DIR \;
```

Comment: And the cool thing if you want to search in the current directory, you don't have to specify the path, just use dot (.) find . -name NAME.EXT -exec cp -rfp {} /DST_DIR \;

Answer (score 6):

If you're using GNU find,

```
find . -mtime 1 -exec cp -t ~/test/ {} +
```

This works as well as piping the output into `xargs` while avoiding the pitfalls of doing so (it handles embedded spaces and newlines without having to use `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 ...`).

Answer (score -2):

This is the best way for me:

```
cat filename.tsv  |
    while read FILENAME
    do
    sudo find /PATH_FROM/  -name "$FILENAME" -maxdepth 4 -exec cp '{}' /PATH_TO/ \; ;
    done
```