# Batch file to move excel workbook based on file name

Tags: batch-file

I have excel files for each day that are broken down into different folders.  So the path looks like:

```
\\network drive\Workarea\SUBRO\DTR\YTD\2014 January Activity\01.02.14\01.01.14 CVO.xls
\\network drive\Workarea\SUBRO\DTR\YTD\2014 January Activity\01.02.14\01.02.14 CVO.xls
```

and so on for every day. '\network drive\Workarea\SUBRO\DTR\YTD\' is the Root folder.

I need these files moved to

```
\\network drive\Workarea\SUBRO\DTR\CVO Reports
```

There are other excel files in each of the "day" folders, but I need a batch file to move anything that ends with ".14 CVO.xls".

I know I can use

```
MOVE filepath newfolder
```

But I would have to hand type out each one for each day of the week.  Is there a commmand to just grab those ending with ".14 CVO.xls" out of each sub directory from the main folder?

Comment: You can use the `find` command. See [this][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17368872/how-to-move-or-copy-files-listed-by-find-command-in-unix

Comment: That was a unix command.  Is there anything for Windows 7?  Sorry, but I work more in databases than with .bat files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To move files from a given folder:

```
move "somePath\*.14 CVO.xls" "newPath"
```

To move all relevent files from all sub folders (any depth) in your root:

```
pushd "\\network drive\Workarea\SUBRO\DTR"
for /d /r "YTD" %%F in ("*.14") do move "%%F\*.14 CVO.xls" "CVO Reports\"
popd
```

The above recursively looks for any folder under `YTD` that ends with `.14`. For each folder found, it then moves any matching file to the new location.

Comment: This is almost doing what I need.  But it is looking for the .14 CVO.xls in the .2014 Files folder.  Within each .2014 Files folder, there is a folder for each day.  Those are the folders where .14 CVO.xls needs searched for.

Comment: @Phil - Did you try it? It should match folders with names like "01.01.2014 Files" and "01.02.2014 Files". Those look like days to me.

Comment: Yes, I ran it, and it only went into the 5 monthly folders looking for .14 CVO.xls files.  Since they weren't they it errored "A duplicate file name exists, or the file cannot be found".  Within each month folder there are folders for the days, then within the day folders, there are 5 excel files, one of which ends with .14 CVO.xls.

Comment: @Phil - Please update (edit) your question to more accurately show examples of your folder structure. For example, show the full path to at least one of the files that is to be moved.

Comment: @Phil - answer updated to match new requirements. In the future, try to be more precise in your original question. The better the original question, the quicker you will get a useful response.