# linux how to move listed files?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, redirect

I tried to redirect the result in a directory but it won't let me do it. What am I doing wrong ?

`find Documents/ -type f -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".+\.(doc|err|out)$" > Poubelle/`

> bash: Poubelle/: Is a directory

What I'm trying to do is move the listed files in Poubelle.
Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you want to achiev? The output of find is a list of files, which can be only redirected to a file. If you want to copy the results, you don't need redirection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find and copy files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241625/find-and-copy-files) or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17368872/how-to-move-or-copy-files-listed-by-find-command-in-unix or ....

Comment: If you're trying to copy or move all the files that `find` lists, you need to use `-exec cp` or `-exec mv`. You might also want to look into using the `rsync` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Barmar said in the comments you need to use `exec` command with `mv` and `cp`.

you can try using below command :

Moving files to Dir :

```
find Documents/ -type f -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".+\.(doc|err|out)$" -exec mv {} Poubelle/ \;
```

Copying files to Dir :

```
find Documents/ -type f -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".+\.(doc|err|out)$" -exec cp {} Poubelle/ \;
```

And you can also use rsync. A simpler form is :

```
rsync source destination
```

For other options read [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync).