# What happened to `cp -t`?

Tags: bash, macos, unix

I was reading up some ways of copying files from a directory with the use of a wildcard operator but excluding one file, and I saw that `cp -t` came into play when used in conjunction with `find`. However, whenever I try to run `cp -t`, I get `cp: illegal option -- t`, which to me means that the flag supplied is not implemented. Is this something that was taken out in more recent versions of bash? For some additional information, I am on macOS Catalina.

Comment: Note that SO is for questions about writing code. Questions about using standard UNIX tools that aren't specifically focused on scripting are a better fit for our sister site [unix.se].

Comment: @bomila : Adding to the answer by KamilCuk : You can install the gnu coreutils for the Mac too. In the installation process, you can choose whether they should get a new name (`gnucp` in your case) or keep the original name (`cp`).

Answer (score 4):

> What happened to `cp -t`?
>
> I am on macOS Catalina.

You were reading [GNU version of `cp`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html) from [GNU coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) that has `-t` option as an extension. And `macOS` has its own versions of standard utils and [macOS cp](https://ss64.com/osx/cp.html) doesn't have `-t`.

> Is this something that was taken out in more recent versions of bash?

`cp` isn't a builtin command, it's not part of bash.

Answer (score 3):

BSD (and thus Mac) `cp` never had this option, which is a GNU extension. It's not hard to write your own replacement, though.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
dst=$1
shift
cp "$@" "$dst"
```

This can be convenient eg. at the end of a `find` or `xargs` pipeline.

```sh
find /tmp -name '*foo*' -exec cpt ~/found/ {} +
```

```sh
mkdir -p backup
cut -d " " -f3- sha2sum.txt | xargs cpt backup
```

Obviously, feel free to adorn this with additional option processing etc as necessary or convenient.

Comment: Of course, adding option processing is the bane of all small elegant shell scripts. Its size will quintuple, and the elegance will disappear.