# Copying Multiple files using cp

Tags: linux

I want to copy multiple files in one go using cp. The problem is that the filenames contain spaces here and there. So I tried `cp $(ls -1|tr ' ' '')  dest` but apparently I cannot truncate to nothing. Then I tried removing null space to spaces. That didnt work either. I tried running it over a for loop. That too didnt work. Can some one please help me????

Comment: try to escape the whitespace, just write `\ ` instead of a simple whitespace.

Comment: tried this `cp $(ls|tr '\ ' '\') /home/user` ,  `cp $(ls|tr ' ' '\') /home/user` , `cp $(ls|tr ' ' '\ ') /home/user`.......nthng works

Comment: I don't understand: do you want also rename files to remove spaces? Or do you want just copy them?

Comment: cp * /home/user/ should work for just copying. The shell should treat each filename from the expansion as a single argument to the command.

Comment: but i dont want to copy all the files

Comment: So do you want pass all files to copy like parameters, for example:

`cp "test one.txt" "test two.txt" dest/`

Am i right?

Comment: yes. but the problem being i have 22 files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try using `find` in combination with `xargs` and `cp`.  See [How can I use xargs to copy files that have spaces and quotes in their names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143171/how-can-i-use-xargs-to-copy-files-that-have-spaces-and-quotes-in-their-names) for more info.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got the answer from that post. `find . -exec cp "{}" dest \;`

Answer (score 0):

Ahn, ok.

I was writing this:

```
for i in *
do
if echo $i | grep " "
then
    NEWNAME=`echo $i | tr ' ' '_'`
    mv "$i" $NEWNAME
fi
done
```

But in this case you rename the file (and of course you have to adapt the code to your needs)
I have this function in my .bashrc

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't `tr` the *source* file names for `cp` - you have to give it the names of the files as they exist on disk or it won't find them.  So it sounds like what you effectively want is to `cp "file with spaces" destdir/filewithspaces` for each individual file:

```
ls -1 | while read filename; do
  cp "$filename" "$dest/${filename// /}" 
done
```

The `${filename// /}` is an instance of the bash-ism `${variable//search/replacement}` (see [shell parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) in the Bash manual) to give the value of a variable with all instances of the `search` string replaced with the `replacement` string - so in this case replace all spaces with nothing.

Comment: says cannot create regular file

Comment: @HariKMalayath does it tell you _which_ file it can't create?  You can't use this exact code if the current directory contains any subdirectories, or if the destination directory is under the source one.

Comment: all 22 of them cannot be created. No the destination is somewhere else