# Trying to grep a find -print0 causes strange behavior

Tags: bash, grep, find, null-character

I have a folder full of directories/files with spaces in their names, and I want to copy all of the `*.ttf` files to another directory **except for the folders `Consolas` and `System Volume Information`**. Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/143172/4077294) post, I tried:

```
find ... -print0  | grep -v "System Volume Information" --null | grep -v "Consolas" --null | xargs -0 cp -t destination
```

For some reason, this results in a `Binary file (standard input) matches` message from the first grep. Using egrep to combine the filters, I attempted:

```
find . -name '*.ttf' -print0 | egrep -v "(System Volume Information)|(Consolas)" --null | xargs...
```

But in this case, egrep will print out *nothing* to the terminal, even though there are plenty of other folders besides `System Volume Information` and `Consolas`. When I removed all but the `find` part of the command, I got one large chunk of text with no newlines, because of the `-print0` option. Since the whole block included `Consolas`, by omitting it I was omitting *everything*. I confirmed this when I tried doing a `grep Arial` on the results and the whole block was printed out.

How should I prevent this behavior in grep?

Comment: You're telling `find` to output a null terminated list, you're not telling `grep` to read a null terminated list, you need an additional `--null-data` for both `greps`

Comment: @BroSlow after hours of searching, thank you very much for the `--null-data`, and don't mistake `-Z` and `-z` !!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is expected behavior of using '-v' option of grep.  It's doing what your telling it to by not giving you any lines that contain Consolas.  To avoid this don't use -print0 and post process with xargs (as you've already discovered) or if you really needed to run everything together do it after the 'grep -v' filters via something like this:

echo -n $(find . -name '*.ttf' | grep -v "System Volume Information" --null | grep -v "Consolas" --null)

but you probably don't need that for this problem as xargs is sufficient.

Comment: I attempted to do a `cp -t dest $(rest_of_command)`, but it seems like the folders with spaces were still not handled properly. Perhaps this isn't an `xargs` issue?

Comment: Try the following.

    cp -t dest ` `echo -n $(...)` `