# bash variable expansion and quoting for part of find command

Tags: bash, variable-expansion

I have some code like the following inside a Bash script:

```
FileNames=""
while read -r FileName; do
    ...
    FileNames+=" -o -iname \"$FileName\""
    ...
done <"$ListOfFileNames"
FileNames="${FileNames# -o }"
find foo -type f \( $FileNames \)
```

This was generally working for me until I found that some file names contain spaces (and maybe other special characters).  When I added the extra quoting around the use of `$FileName` to cover these cases, the expansion of `$FileNames` within the `find` command starts misbehaving.  I have tried various other ways of quoting and escaping and came up empty. I have successfully used variables in many other ways in many other scripts I have written, but this one has baffled me.  I am running the script under Cygwin.  Is there some nice way to handle this?

Comment: I was just looking for the answer to this myself. [Here ya go.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/143172/6142694)

Comment: Barmar, the reference you provide did not show up the way I searched, but I see it is basically the same issue.  However, I would say that it is not an 'exact duplicate' as it did not have to deal with quoting a nested expansion and then deleting part of the variable (which I got wrong the first time I tried the array method).

Comment: Daniel, I didn't actually see that the place your link sent me explained my problem with variable expansion within a command, but it's water under the bridge now.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array. Arrays can handle whitespace much better. To be extra safe, also use `IFS=` to preserve leading whitespace with `read`.

```
FileNames=(-false)
while IFS= read -r FileName; do
    ...
    FileNames+=(-o -iname "$FileName")
    ...
done < "$ListOfFileNames"
find foo -type f \( "${FileNames[@]}" \)
```

Comment: Thanks John, this worked except I had to figure out how to correctly get the `FileNames="${FileNames# -o }"` functionality. At first I just set the first array element to "", but that didn't work.  `unset` did work.