# Makefile rule that writes to /dev/tty inside a subshell?

Tags: bash, makefile, sh

```
$ cat Makefile
clean:
    find . -print0 | grep -z pattern | tee >\(tr '\0' '\n' > /dev/tty\) | xargs -0 rm
$ make clean
/bin/sh: /dev/tty): Permission denied
```

Previous question:

[How can I display intermediate pipeline results for NUL-separated data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44730184)

Comment: By default, make uses `/bin/sh`, which means you don't have bash-only syntax such as process substitution.

Comment: BTW, is there a reason you're using `grep`, rather than telling `find` to exclude files matching the pattern itself? That would moot the need for a process substitution at all, since you could run `find . -path '*pattern*' -prune -o -print -exec rm -- {} +` or such. (Of course, I'd advise using `-name` rather than `-path` if possible).

Comment: Actually, turns out we already have an on-point question and answer. :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm using two grep commands to exclude some things with -v, and include other things without -v.  But also laziness, I avoided learning all the ins and outs of the swiss-army knives.  And I like composing pipelines with simple pieces.  Can you do `find . | grep -v p1 | grep p2 | xargs` with just find?  Agreed that make syntax is kind of terrible, I probably should have stuck with the multi-line rules.  Still, I learned something today...

Comment: Yes, you can do both positive and negative tests in the same `find` invocation. `find . -path p1 ! -path p2 -exec ...`

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind is probably a good place to start.

Comment: Cheers.  I deleted my previous comment about learning find, but that was before I saw yours...

Comment: except, of course, for section 7.1, "Nasty OS X bug", precluding the use of -exec ... + on my system

Comment: That bug really matters to you for your current use case? When is `rm -f` going to fail? And you can, of course, use `-exec ... {} \;` instead (at a performance penalty, but nonetheless).

Comment: Fair enough.  I guess my gut reaction if something isn't going to work consistently is to avoid using it, but it's not always appropriate.  In this case it seems the best thing is to do is to just install findutils.